# How to improve VATS weapon accuracy

Tags: fallout-4

What are the different options to improve weapon accuracy. And is it in all the cases capped at 95%?

Comment: Kind of out of scope, but crits are 100% accuracy.

Comment: @mmatthews That would mean that maxing the others doesn't matter at all. You better go for that 100% critial hit chance, do more overall dmg and have the 100% hitquote.

Comment: That's been my strat: build crits and bank crits.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your VATS accuracy with ranged weapons depends on:

- Your character's Perception stat (which means it is improved indirectly by anything which raises Perception)
- Weapon accuracy stat
- Weapon range stat (higher means less accuracy loss at larger distances)
- Any equipment which explicitly gives a bonus to VATS accuracy. You can sometimes find such items as random drops from rare enemies with a  ★ behind their name.
- Any perks which give you an explicit bonus to VATS accuracy in certain situations:

  - Awareness 2 (5% accuracy)
  - Sniper 3 (25% accuracy for headshots with a non-automatic scoped rifle)
  - Penetrator 2 (no accuracy penalty for cover)
  - Concentrated Fire 1-3 (+10%/+15%/+20% accuracy for repeated shots)
  - Attack Dog 1 (accuracy bonus while your dog is holding the enemy)
  - Killshot (20% accuracy bonus for headshots) - this is a bonus perk obtained by maxing the relationship score with the companion character MacCready.

The 95% cap is a lie. Even though the UI never *shows* more than 95% accuracy, you can gain enough VATS accuracy that you never miss a shot.

Comment: @mmatthews comment brought me to a nice idea: One could completely ignore the accuracy and focusing solely on luck. Max is as high as possible and use all the gear you can find, to have a better hitchance and even more damage on top of that. Or it there a flaw in that idea?

Comment: @TrudleR That would be a new question.

Comment: Ok, I created one, thanks. :) https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334650/is-leveling-vats-accurracy-actually-worth-it-compared-to-luck

Comment: MacCready Perk is really nice in VATS.